# Check whether the following sequence of functions are uniformly convergent or not? $ (\sin(x))^n $, x $\in$ $ [0,π/2[$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Check whether the following sequence of functions are uniformly convergent or not?
$$ f_n(x)=(\sin(x))^n,\qquad x  \in   [0,π/2)
$$

Limiting function is continuous. So , I could not do anything with that. I  tried to use M-test, it is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Use that ${\rm lim}\ [{\rm sup}\ \{ |  f_n(x)-f(x)|\ :\ x\in [0,\pi/2 )]=1.$ (See this related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652696/prove-xn-is-not-uniformly-convergent).

Comment: You should tell us what you found for the pointwise limit function.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** no, there is no uniform convergence. To see how to prove this, let us come up with some sequence $(x_n)_n$ such that $f_n(x_n)$ does not converge to $0$. *Below, I describe in detail how to find such a sequence.*

---

Since $\sin x \to  1$ when $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}$, intuitively the issue should be "around $\frac{\pi}{2}$." Thus, we want to find $x_n$ of the form $\frac{\pi}{2}-o(1)$, for the "right" $o(1)$.

Let $(\varepsilon_n)_n$ be a sequence converging to $0$ that we will pick later, according to our needs, and consider $$x_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{\pi}{2}-\varepsilon_n$$
for $n\geq 1$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
f_n(x_n) &= \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\varepsilon_n)^n
= (\cos \varepsilon_n)^n
= \left(1-\frac{\varepsilon_n^2}{2}+o(\varepsilon_n^2)\right)^n
\\&= \exp\left(n\ln\left(1-\frac{\varepsilon_n^2}{2}+o(\varepsilon_n^2)\right)\right)\\&
= \exp\left(-\frac{n\varepsilon_n^2}{2}+o(n\varepsilon_n^2)\right)
 \end{align}$$
using the Taylor expansions of $\cos u$ and $\ln(1+u)$ at $0$ (and the assumption that $\varepsilon_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$).

This means that, choosing ${n\varepsilon_n^2}={2}$, i.e. $$
\varepsilon_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}
$$
we get, for $x_n=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}$, that
$$\begin{align}
f_n(x_n) &= \exp\left(-1+o(1)\right) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{e} \neq 0.
 \end{align}$$ 
Thus, we do not have uniform convergence, as
$$
\sup_{x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})} \lvert f_n(x)\rvert \geq \lvert f_n(x_n)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{e} > 0.
$$

Comment: $x_n = \arcsin (1/2^{1/n})$ or something might be quicker.

Comment: I didn't try to make it as quick as possible, I tried to make it didactic @zhw

Comment: Is there any quicker way to deduce the nature of convergence. What are the short cuts(theorems) useful to judge the nature?

Comment: I don't have one off the top of my mind, but what do you want one big hammer while the above is actually pretty fast? If you remove all the discussion trying to get the intuition, it boils down to "consider $f_n(x_n)$ for $x_n = \pi/2-1/\sqrt{n}$ (or the one above suggested by zhw); show the limit is non-zero" which takes a couple lines.