# Proving $f(x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} + ... $ is continuous for a fixed $x_0 \in (-1,1)$ by using the Weierstrass M-test

Tags: functions, continuity, proof-writing, power-series, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that $f(x) = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} + ...$ is continuous for a fixed $x_0 \in (-1,1)$ by using the Weierstrass M-test. Now, the solution in the book is not what I expected, and not even close to what I had in my own mind. So, can some one verify if I am totally of with my approach to solve this

Here was my suggestion:

Let $M_n = x^n$, then for each $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ we have that $f_n(x) \leq M_n$. We know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} M_n$ converges since it is a geometric series, hence  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges uniformly by Weierstrass M-test, and by the Continuous Limit Theorem f(x) is continuous at $x_0$.

I guess there is a mistake here somewhere...could anybody point it out for me?

Comment: Your $M_n$ are not constant, so that might be a mistake...

Comment: Would you mind briefly describing the solution given in your book ?

Comment: You have to take a look at $f\vert_{[-a, a]}$ for some fixed $a \in (-1, 1)$.

Comment: In $(-1,1)$ , we have $f(x)=-\ln(1-x)$ , but I do not think that this is supposed to be used.

Comment: @FiMePr  think I found the problem. $M_n$ cannot depend in $x$. It has to be that $|f_n(x)| \leq M_n$ for all $x \in (-1,1)$

Comment: Do you agree with me on this @Peter?

Comment: Thus, I think @Shaqinho is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think you can prove it like this: just choose $a \in (-1, 1)$ such that $x_0 \in (-a, a)$. Then for your $f_n$ the inequality $\lvert f_n(x) \rvert \leq \frac{a^n}{n} =: M_n$ holds for all $x \in [-a, a]$. Obviously $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} M_n < \infty$ is true (just estimate it by a geometric series). Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-a, a]$, i.e. $f \lvert_{[-a, a]}$ is continuous. But as $x_0 \in [-a, a]$, this is all we wanted.

Comment: Yes!! This is the way to do. Thanks!

Comment: If by "just estimate it by a geometric series" you mean using the series built on $x^n$, then uniform convergence is not ensured in $(-1,1)$. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652696/65203 $[-a,a]$ is not sufficient.

Comment: I don't know what you want to tell me. Do you know the Weierstraß M-Test?

Comment: @Shaqinho: do you know the difference between $[-a,a]$ and $(-1,1)$ ?

Comment: Yes and it's massive. You can prove (as i did) that $\displaystyle F_n(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} f_n(x)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on every interval $[-a, a]$, $a \in (-1, 1)$ by using the Weierstraß M-test (I know, it fails for the entire interval $(-1, 1)$). So we can prove that $f \vert_{[-a, a]}$ is continuous for every $a \in (-1, 1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for continuity can be written

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_0^k}{k}.$$

As the series converge absolutely, we can subtract term-wise and

$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k-x_0^k}{k}=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x^ix_0^{k-1-i}
\\\le\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_1^k
=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_1^k
\\=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{x-x_0}{1-x_1}=0$$
where we have chosen a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $x,x_0<x_1<1$.